# How to keep Adobe Reader DC from deleting it's installer exe?

Tags: adobe-reader, adobe-reader-dc

When you run Adobe Reader DC's installer, upon completion, it will delete the .exe file that was run.

If you make copies, this works, but you have to remember to copy it every time, and this is annoying and prone to accidentally forgetting and having to download it again.

Google hasn't resulted in any successful solutions. Everything I find is just people with the same issue, and no answer given, just more people adding on to the complaints of this annoyance.

How do you prevent Adobe from deleting its own installer, so it can be reused on multiple machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my own testing, if you set the .exe file to `Read-only`, it will not self-delete.

While typically this setting doesn't affect deleting files, it seems Adobe checks for this when deciding whether to delete the installer or not.

[image: Adobe installer set to Read-only]